# Matlab: extracting positions of numbers (integer and decimal) from a string

Tags: regex, string, matlab

I want to extract positions of numbers (and their length) from strings that represent expressions like

```
f1 = '(z-(z.^3-5)./(3.*z.^2))';
```

I got this for single integers (see code below) but for larger integers or decimal numbers

```
f2 = '(z-(z.^3-21)./(341.*z.^2))';
f3 = '(z-(z.^3-5.347)./(35.4983.*z.^2))';
```

the case-by-case analysis becomes increasingly confusing for me. Perhaps the general case could be solved easier with regular expressions?

```
num_list = zeros(2,f1_length); 
k=1; 
for i=1:f1_length
    if isempty(str2num(f1(i)))
        continue; 
    else
        num_list(1,k) = i; num_list(2,k) = 1; k=k+1; 
    end
end;
```

After deleting of the remaining 0's on the right I got for '(z-(z.^3-5)./(3.*z.^2))'

```
8    10    15    21
1     1     1     1
```

Comment: What is the actual goal of getting the strings here? Are you trying to parse the expression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can definitely do this with regular expressions. The following pattern should match numbers

```
pattern = '(\d*\.)?\d+';
```

You can then use the `'start'` and `'end'` options to `regexp` to determine the starting and ending characters

```
starts = regexp(f1, pattern);
ends = regexp(f1, pattern, 'end');

numlist = [starts; (ends - starts) + 1];
```